# Adding Laika auto-numbering to top-level directory titles

Tags: scala, autonumber, laika

I have the `directory.conf`:

```
title = "SRLLab Manual"

autonumbering {
  scope: all
}

navigationOrder = [
  introduction
  multi-arm-bandits
  finite-markov-decision-processes
]
```

In each of the sub-level directories I have a `directory.conf` and a Markdown file. When I generate the site no numbering appears in the top-level directory titles. Is their any way to automatically add numbering to the top level?

I have this set-up [here](https://gitlab.com/hmf/srllab).

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add numbering from the second level down you must also add the

```
autonumbering {
  scope: all
}
```

section to each of the sub-directories `directory.conf` files.